# Modular page layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to display certain things on every or almost every page of my application. Things like header, footer, sidebar or navigation.

How would I go about doing that? I am coming from languages like PHP and ColdFusion where I would either include files or call a function to display what I want. I am having a hard time understanding how I can implement it in Rails.

Comment: Comprehensive explanation of working with layouts is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in your application layout, you use partials. A small example would look like

```
<body>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/footer' %>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should have `app/view/layouts/application.html.erb`. That's where your html content goes.

In the application.html.erb, you should see `<%= yield %>`. This is where specific views for different controller actions with corresponding views go.

For your css files for application.html.erb, you should use `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`.

For your javascript files for application.html.erb, you should use `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.